At what point should we suspect unfair game?
In probability theory, there are two primary approaches to interpreting events: the frequentist perspective and the Bayesian perspective.
From a frequentist standpoint, each spin of a fair roulette wheel is an independent event with a 50% chance of landing on black. According to this view, no matter how many consecutive black outcomes are observed, the probability of the next spin being black remains 50%. This principle helps avoid the "Gambler's Fallacy," where one might incorrectly believe that past events influence future independent events.
On the other hand, the Bayesian approach involves updating our beliefs based on new evidence. If we observe a series of black outcomes, a Bayesian would consider the extremely low probability of such a sequence occurring by chance if the wheel were fair. Bayes' Theorem allows us to update the probability of the wheel being biased based on the observed data. The more consecutive black outcomes we observe, the stronger the evidence that the wheel might be biased.
Given these two perspectives, I have a question:
At what point (i.e., after how many consecutive black spins) should we reasonably start to suspect that the roulette wheel might be biased and thus incline towards a Bayesian approach? How do we determine this threshold, and what factors should we consider when making this decision? Specifically, how do we balance the theoretical independence of events with the practical improbability of long sequences of identical outcomes in a fair game?

I don't really understand why you're asking this question here. I think this is a purely technical (+practical) question about probability theory and statistics. Have you tried first asking the question on a math or statistics forum? Otherwise - how is philosophy involved here?

@DikranMarsupial - I agree with your statement - I just did not really see that play out in the OPs question - probably because of the way it is expressed. I am fully +1 on your answer below - very precise criticism + correction on the question.

Based on past experience and unfolding events we would have to make an educated guess. Otherwise known as an inference.

There are statistical tests to determine fairness. The chi-squared goodness of fit is an example.

This question is similar to: How improbable does an event have to be before we can say it didn't happen by chance?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

"Probability theory" - the main tool (available for us) to discourage atheist views on the materialistic world. The facts of our reality that blow away any probability calculations (extremely unfair roulette wheel) are all around us (including Darwin's theory of evolution applied on a molecular level). But scientists conveniently try to close eyes on it with the reasoning of a lack of scientific facts.

You start with "From a frequentist standpoint, each spin of a fair roulette wheel ..." (emphasis mine). The frequentist approach you describe is in response to this question, where "the wheel is fair" is a hard coded assumption. If you asked a frequentist "[when] should we reasonably start to suspect that the roulette wheel might be biased?", they would suggest a different approach.
Asking the Bayesian the real question you're interested in, and the frequentist a different one, doesn't seem like a good way to compare the two approaches.

I think that is a fair criticism of how the question is formulated :| But the final question seems to make clear that the OP wants to start from a frequentist point of view - so, really without making that assumption. It's just that this whole question imo can be answered simply by setting some significance level for a null hypothesis and doing the calculation...

Yeah, hypothesis testing is how one could approach it in Stats 101, but there is also some real detailed mathematical research on "when should I stop while doing a variable-length sequence of experiments". As your comment on the main question noted, the real answer is a bunch of technical details, but it's written looking for a fight between the two big schools.

A quick bit of searching turns up the phrase "stopping rules" for the term of art in statistics. It also turns up mostly Bayesians! There's also discussion about using mixed models, combining Baysian and frequentist approaches. But it's all very practical and engineer-y, based on costs and risks, and doesn't seem to involve philosophy.

You start with some estimate of how likely it is, before the spins, that the wheel is rigged to only roll black. Then you look at the chance the wheel would have produced the sequence of spins if it was fair. If the latter is less likely than the former, then you can be 50% confident that the wheel is rigged.
The prior estimate depends on where you find the wheel. If a friend wanted to show you something cool, then the chance the wheel is rigged is quite high. If the wheel was instead in some large casino, then the casino operator would not benefit from making it only roll black and would only stand to be sued and fined, so the chance it is rigged in that case is very low. The only way for it to be rigged in a large casino would be some elaborate sabotage by someone trying to discredit the casino.
So maybe 1 in 1000 if a friend wants to show you something cool (taking into account the technical difficulty of rigging it to only roll black), and 1 in 1 million for the casino. That would correspond to about 10 black rolls for the friend, or 20 for the casino.
Note: here's how you get this decision method from Bayes' theorem.
P(rigged | observation) = P(observation | rigged) P(rigged)/P(observation) = 1 * P(rigged)/(P(rigged) P(observation|rigged) + P(not rigged) P(observation|not rigged)) = P(rigged)/(P(rigged) * 1 + P(not rigged) P(observation|not rigged))
which is roughly equal to P(rigged)/(P(rigged) + P(observation|not rigged)) because P(not rigged) is roughly 1. So if P(observation|not rigged) is less than P(rigged), then P(rigged|observation) will be above 0.5.

0.1 cent.
There is no hard threshold that can be set, but depends on how much fair/unfair the real roulette is.
If it is only slightly unfair, then a large(r) number of samples would be required to infer unfairness with adequate significance; on the other hand if the unfairness is great, then relatively less number of samples are necessary to infer unfairness.
Usually, in hypothesis testing, some threshold(s) are preselected before testing the hypothesis (eg this is used at CERN experiments with the five sigma criterion). This means that different threshold(s) can make a different hypothesis seem plausible. In other words, accepted hypothesis is a function of the threshold(s).
Something similar has been asked on math.se How many rolls do I need to determine if my dice are fair?. Therein, similarly to this answer, number of rolls given depend on (preselected) significance level, test power and detected effect size. (One can use the tools used in that answer to  get a numeric answer to your question)

Choosing significance level = .05, power = 0.80, degrees of freedom =
num sides - 1, and effect size = 0.5, I find the following sample sizes to test the fairness of 6-sided, 10-sided, and 20-sided dice:
6-sided: 52 rolls
10-sided: 63 rolls
20-sided: 83 rolls


The real problem of statistics is how to know we indeed have a representative sample of some population. Statistics practice relies mostly on heuristics (eg random sampling) in order to address this problem.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
